# Show all tab content in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I show all the panes in an "all" tab using [jQuery UI tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution. What I did was:

```
var user_tabs = $("#user-tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.index == 0) {
            $("div[id^=tabs-pane-]").show();
        } else {
            $("div[id^=tabs-pane-]").hide();
            $(ui.panel).show()
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show all the divs in your main tab div ?

```
function ShowAll(){
  $('div#tabs div').show()
}
```

It could be a nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work.

```
$("div.ui-tabs-hide").removeClass("ui-tabs-hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

for jquery ui tabs 1.12.1:

```
$("#user-tabs").tabs(
    {activate:
            function(event, ui) {
                if ( "do some checking here if the special show-all tab was selected") {
                    $("div[id^='tabs-pane-']").show();
                }
            }
        }
    )
```